# jQuery setInterval if statement loop is not working

Tags: jquery, if-statement, setinterval

I have a jquery setInterval function that will not work. I'm new to jQuery, but this seems like it should work and I have checked my code making sure their are no problems. Is there anyway that if statements don't work in jQuery?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $varadd = "0";

    var interval = setInterval(timecode, 8000);

    function timecode() {
        $varadd = $varadd + 1;

        if ($varadd == "1"){
            // function 1
        }
        elseif ($varadd == "2"){
            // function 2
        }
        elseif ($varadd == "3"){
            // function 3
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: `$varadd` is currently a string. Using the + operator will concatenate the character `"1"` to the end of it. Remove quotes and try again.

Comment: @Asad: Interestingly, using `$varadd++;` will convert it to a number.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yeah, that's because the production steps for postfix increment include `ToNumber(GetValue(lhs))`. (First thing on page 70 of [this document](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf), if you want to have a look)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick run of your code in jsfiddle reveals the issue.  it's `else if` not `elseif` in javascript.  Without any other context,  I can at least tell you that you do, in fact, have an error in your code.  Learn to use (and love!) the javascript console.

Comment: Thank You! That worked perfectly. I can't believe it was that easy. I guess i'm just used to PHP elseif